# Postback delegate is null

Tags: c#, events, postback, custom-server-controls

I am building server control  with custom events and as example used this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719907%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).But events are never fired while postback - clickEventDelegate is always null:

```
      if (clickEventDelegate != null)
      {
            clickEventDelegate(this, e);
      }
```

Here is how I add delegate:

```
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
          .....
         MYCONTROL.LeftClick+= FUNCTION;
     }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You did not post enough of your code to find out why your event is null. But I am gonna list the standard pattern.

This is how you define an argument class for your custom event:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string MyField { get; private set; }

    public MyEventArgs(string myField)
    {
        MyField = myField;
    }
}
```

This is how you define a custom event:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

This is how you write an event raiser in the same class as the event:

```
protected virtual void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<MyEventArgs> myEvent = MyEvent; // for thread safety
    if (myEvent != null)
    {
        myEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

This is how you raise the event in the class it is defined in (or a derived class):

```
OnMyEvent(new MyEventArgs("Test"));
```

This is how you react to the event in a derived class:

```
protected override void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Here you react to your event.
    base.OnMyEvent(e);
}
```

This is how you register on the event in a foreign class:

```
otherClass.MyEvent += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Here you react to your event.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer just explains how events work but is completely ignoring the main point of the question: **Delegate is null during a postback**

The answer was quite simple. Just subscribe to your event every times even during Postback, so you just had to remove your condition `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

```
MYCONTROL.LeftClick+= FUNCTION;
```

I know this is a very old question and there is no way you are still searching for the answer. But when I read

> You did not post enough of your code to find out why your event is
>   null

from the previous answer I couldn't let this wrong statement like this.

**EDIT:**

To add more explanations, every time the server returns the final page to be rendered in the browser it then looses the state of this particular connection. Imagine if the server should keep in memory all connections with their associated states, you have maybe thousands of users a day, and also when to "clean" this memory?

So no that won't be doable that's why they created the `ViewState` so the browser can send previous information to the server. However this ViewState can save values of some variables or objects but doesn't save the binding between an event and its delegate(s).

Back to concrete examples. If you do this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonTest" OnClick="buttonTest_Click" Text="test" />
```

The subscription to the event is made internally by ASP.NET on a very early stage in the life cycle before you reach the page's `Page_Load`. You can read about the ASP.NET life cycle [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

If you assign the event handler like this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonTest" Text="test" />
```

and on your page's server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonTest.Click += ButtonTest_Click;
}
```

It will work the same except that the subscription is made a bit later.

But if instead you decorate it in a condition

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ButtonTest.Click += ButtonTest_Click;
    }
}
```

This won't work because the event handler has not been assigned. Remember that your server forgot the state of this particular connection and has to initialize everything at each HTTP POST request (PostBack).

This is exactly like in the sample code of your question, so as you can see events are working the same on native ASP.NET controls or custom ones you declared.

Comment: I confirm that subscribe every time it post back will work. But why it works that way, and how about default event like Click, should subscribe on post back or not?